# Three.js instancing equivalent

Tags: three.js

I've recently started playing with three.js. Noticed that even with a few thousand simple cubes, the performance starts to drop.

So this brings my main question: is there any way to instance using three.js? I'm pretty sure this drop in performance is related to the drawcalls, therefore if instancing is possible with three.js somehow, it can help support the performance.

I'm aware of buffers but at this point it's impossible for me to create a geometry buffer that will give me the power to modify individual objects during runtime. If there is a library to handle all this, this also counts as a solution.

Shortly, I'm looking for an equivalent of **object instancing** in three.js. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_instancing_dynamic.html and http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_instancing.html

Answer (score 4):

I've understood that instancing can be emulated / reimplemented with a shader. Am not sure and have not tried though.

This old demo has 150k individually animated cubes on the GPU btw, but the source is minified so was hard to see what's going on. Perhaps not a proper instancing solution that would work for any mesh, am not sure, might even be. http://alteredqualia.com/three/examples/webgl_cubes.html

Will keep an eye open for this as we'd need it too I think.. (have added trees to vizicities in a demo now)

Answer (score 2):

I have only thought up a solution and have not tried it yet. I want to instance very complex meshes and have them animated using a skeleton. It seems the JSON loader only loads as Geometry G. I want to convert to BufferGeometry BG1, than make another BufferGeometry BG2. Then assign references of vertex attributes, etc from BG2 to BG1

```
//load mesh
...
var mesh = loadMesh();

//convert to buffer geometry
var BG1 = new BufferGeometry();
BG1.fromGeometry(mesh);

var BG2 = new BufferGeometry();
BG2.addAttribute('position', G1.attributes['position']);
BG2.addAttribute('normal', G1.attributes['normal']);
BG2.addAttribute('uv', G1.attributes['uv']);
BG2.addAttribute('color', G1.attributes['color']);

BG2.drawcalls = BG1.drawcalls;
BG2.boundingBox = BG1.boundingBox;
BG2.boundingSphere = BG1.boundingSphere;
```

Its my understanding that webgl will share these buffers and not duplicate the memory used in VRAM. Any comments are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same experience when trying to draw a couple of thousands of Spheres.

After some research I achieved a better performance (up to a million of items) using the [PointCloud](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Objects/PointCloud) Object. Basically you create the PointCloud object from a geometry (it can be created from raw in this example or use one of the existing in Three.js) and the PointCloudMaterial, where you can modify the properties of each item.

An example could be as follows (adding 10 points)

```
var geo = new THREE.Geometry();
var mat = new THREE.PointCloudMaterial({size: 1, color:0xff0000});

//assign different positions to the points
for (var i=0 ; i<10 ; i++){
  var point = new THREE.Vector3(3*i,0,0);
  geo.vertices.push(point);
}

system = new THREE.PointCloud(geo, mat);
scene.add(system);
```

To modify the appearance, you can play with the PointCloudMaterial properties, or load a texture so that each point gets a desired shape (cube-like in your case).

If you share more details (why do you need cubes, for example) or some code, maybe I can be more helpful

Comment: each point is a single point though, right? What if I want to duplicate 10000 cubes? Spheres look similar from every angle but something like a cube (or a more complex geometry) needs to be actually 3d.

Comment: That's true. Each point of a PointCloud consist just of three coordinates x,y,z. I could think of two approaches, that are not the direct solution, but may work depending on your needs:

Comment: I'm looking for a proper object instancing method. Drawing cubes manually would be pretty easy but drawing an imported modal would be incredibly hard.. Shortly, as I stated, I need a way to instance geometry, with the access of individual position scale rotation for each element.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers here are extremely outdated.

THREE.js now supports instancing via InstancedMesh
https://threejs.org/docs/?q=instancedmesh#api/en/objects/InstancedMesh

See example here:
https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_instancing.html